# Delete ALBUM Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hi All does anyone know the correct Graph path for deleting an album? I have tried a bunch of things and nothing seems to work?

```
/me/aid
/aid
/me/object_id/albums
/me/object_id
/me/albums/object_id
/object_id/album"
/object_id/albums
/object_id
```

obviously replacing `aid` and `object_id` with a valid value...

Is it possible to delete an album through the Graph API? thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Umm, as far as I can tell, you simply are not allowed to delete an album through the graph API, regardless of permissions.

This has been true for a while.

Recently (its 1/16/12 when I write this), graph API users can't even delete photos.

Here's the Facebook Bug Link:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/125524667559003?browse=search_4f14be86ba58f3666689319

Yes, the FB-built apps appear to have special permissions linked to their App IDs to which you do not have access.  I just noticed, for instance, that the iOS app uploads photos to a temporary album while you are typing in the caption for the photo so the final "upload" wait is perceived to be just a few seconds (it just moves the picture to the mobile uploads album and set the privacy).  Access to anything like a temp album is not available through any API I can see.

Filing a bug report is about all you can do.

I would be happy to have this answer down voted as not correct, but I have spent a reasonable amount of time not just looking at the docs, but watching what the iOs app is doing through a proxy server and trying to recreate it.

Comment: i get this response indeed ...{"error":{"message":"(#200) Application does not have the capability to make this API call.","type":"OAuthException","code":200}}

Answer (score 2):

From Facebook's documentation:

---

You can delete objects in the graph by issuing HTTP DELETE requests to the object URLs, i.e,

DELETE https://graph.facebook.com/ID?access_token=... HTTP/1.1
To support clients that do not support all HTTP methods (like JavaScript clients), you can alternatively issue a POST request to an object URL with the additional argument method=delete to override the HTTP method. For example, you can delete a comment by issuing a POST request to https://graph.facebook.com/COMMENT_ID?method=delete.

You can delete a like by issuing a DELETE request to /POST_ID/likes (since likes don't have an ID).

---

So the last one of your paths is the correct one '/object_id'. You need to make sure you are either sending your HTTP request as a "DELETE" or as a "POST" with the query parameter method=delete set. For example:

DELETE https://graph.facebook.com/ID?access_token=
or
POST https://graph.facebook.com/ID?method=delete&access_token=

If neither of those work, make sure you have the correct extended permission. I believe the permission you need to delete an album is 'publish_stream'. I have never done it before so I could be wrong on that one.

If you are using the Facebook C# SDK you would do it like this:

```
var client = new FacebookClient('access_token');
dynamic result = client.Delete('object_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could read the ID of a certain album by /me/albums/ and after that run the delete on https://graph.facebook.com/ID

On my try it worked just fine...

Comment: Thanks for the response.. So my original message shows the path's i've tried and none of them work. You say you tried and it worked, can you please give me some more details? Are you using the object_id or the album_id? Sorry in my list above i forgot to mention the obvious path i've tried which is /object_id . Thanks again!

Comment: it worked with the object_id... Have you tried to open that id in the browser (e.g. https://graph.facebook.com/123456)... does the JSON show? If so you can delete it...

Comment: Yes it shows, definitely exists. I am using the as3 facebook api so i'm assuming the problem is with this API. Going to grab the source today and check it out.

Answer (score 0):

To delete objects via the AS3 Facebook API, use the `deleteObject(method,callback)` function of the `Facebook` object.