# Is it possible to delete photos/ albums of the current user on facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

Well, is there any way to delete user photos or albums via facebook Graph API? I've seen [Delete ALBUM Facebook Graph API?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4831324/1786117), but I am not quite sure if this is up to date. Is there any way to do this with any sdk provided by facebook?
(I would however prefer something related to php sdk, since I am more familiar with it)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so (for albums), I had the same issue some days ago and apparently, an application does not have the capability to make this kind of API call.